# Cannot switch account when using Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, flutter, dart

The app allows the user to sign in using Facebook, but I am having trouble with when the user wants to use a different Facebook account to sign in, this page will only show the continue button. Is there a way for the user to choose to use a different account for signing in?

````
   Future<User> signInWithFacebook() async {
    final fb = FacebookLogin();
    final response = await fb.logIn(permissions: [
      FacebookPermission.publicProfile,
      FacebookPermission.email,
    ]);

    switch (response.status) {
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Success:
        final accessToken = response.accessToken;
        final userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(
          FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.token),
        );
        return userCredential.user;

      case FacebookLoginStatus.Cancel:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_ABORTED_BY_USER',
          message: 'Sign in aborted by user',
        );
      case FacebookLoginStatus.Error:
        throw FirebaseAuthException(
          code: 'ERROR_FACEBOOK_LOGIN_FAILED',
          message: response.error.developerMessage,
        );
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError();
    }
  }
  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
    await googleSignIn.signOut();
    final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
    await facebookLogin.logOut();
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }```
````